# Extracting specific row based on a specific criteria Windows batch file

Tags: windows, csv, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a simple batch file to do the following:

- Read the lines of a text file; each line contains a `team`.
- Find the data with that criteria from several `CSV` files. (Each team could have many rows)
- Copy the result in one `CSV` file.
- Loop till the end of the teams.

`CSV` files contains data like this:

```
"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,

"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,

"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,

"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,

"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,

"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,

......
```

The text file contains:

```
Team A

Team B

Team C

Team D

...
```

---

This is the code I tried:

```
FOR %%A IN (Team.txt) DO Find "%%A" *.csv > result.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How do I extract rows based on a specified criteria?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%t in (team.txt) do (
  for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`findstr /c:"%%t" *.csv`) do (
    set _line=%%i
    rem strip filenames from findstr output
    set _line=!_line:*:=%!
    echo !_line! >> "%%t".csv
  )
)
endlocal
```

Notes:

- `team.txt` contains the *team names*.
- If there are matching lines for a particular team name then an output csv file is created with the name *team name*.csv.

Example usage and output:

```
F:\test>type team.txt
Team A
Team B
Team C
Team D
F:\test>type *.csv

1.csv


"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,
"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,
"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,

2.csv


"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,
"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,
"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,

F:\test>test
processing Team A
processing Team B
processing Team C
processing Team D

F:\test>type t*.csv

Team A.csv


"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,
"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,
"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,
"Team A",2013/06/15 02:14:58 -0400,"X","LQ3SUEEWPWKL6",005,

Team B.csv


"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team B",2014/06/20 03:54:12 -0321,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,

Team C.csv


"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
"Team C",2011/01/14 00:00:00 -0400,"Y","LQ4STREWNBKM5",004,
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [syntax-replace](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) - Variable Edit/Replace

Comment: That was the result I was waiting for.

Answer (score 2):

In `PowerShell`, you could use the [Import-Csv](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113341) cmdlet. Just specify the header for the first column to enable the access using the property name, select it using [Select-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113387) and finally write it to a file using the [Out-File](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113363) cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'your_source_path.csv' -Header "Team" | 
    select -ExpandProperty Team | 
    Out-File 'YourDestination.txt'
```

**File content:**

```
Team A
Team C
Team B
Team A
Team C
Team B
```

Comment: The Import-csv command cannot operate on multiple files. I have 7 csv files and the size of each file is 700Mo.

Comment: Use the `Get-ChildItem` to load your files and pipe it to the `Import-Csv` cmdlet.

Comment: `gc .\teamin.txt |% { sls $_ *.csv | select -Expand Line | out-file -append "$_.out" }` - no need to actually process them as CSV, is there?

Comment: Yes. No need to process them as CSV. The command works perfectly. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file does not have spaces every other line, because that's just weird:

```
for /f "delims=" %t in (teams-in.txt) do (grep "%t" *.csv > "%t.out")
```

Where grep is [grep for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm)

[edit: and don't output to .csv in the same folder as searching *.csv *cough* ]

Comment: Why use `grep` when `find` or `findstr` are already installed?

Comment: @DavidPostill because in a *.csv search, findstr outputs the name of the file into the output strings. And I thought grep didn't ... although I check now, it actually does, so this is a crummy answer.

Comment: I've used some *magic* to strip the filename from the output of `findstr`. See my answer for a fully working batch file solution that does not need any 3rd-party tools.